# The era of Sign with no submission action is different than submit

Tags: era, signed-extensions, polkadot-js

I'm using a ed-25519 account, and first sign with no submission, and use the 「Signed transaction」to decode, the result(right pic) show the era Period is 0x40...

[image]

then I do a real submit, but the extrinsic lifetime shows the era is from #1 to #33. the right pic shows era Period is 0x20...

[image]

My question is why the two era in these two scene is different? I need to make sure these two era keep same, in other words, how can I make era of Sign(no submission) be the same as real submit action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are representing the same thing. The left image is merely a more tangible representation.

`Era` is defined as:

```
pub enum Era {
    /// The transaction is valid forever. The genesis hash must be present in the signed content.
    Immortal,

    /// Period and phase are encoded:
    /// - The period of validity from the block hash found in the signing material.
    /// - The phase in the period that this transaction's lifetime begins (and, importantly,
    /// implies which block hash is included in the signature material). If the `period` is
    /// greater than 1 << 12, then it will be a factor of the times greater than 1<<12 that
    /// `period` is.
    ///
    /// When used on `FRAME`-based runtimes, `period` cannot exceed `BlockHashCount` parameter
    /// of `system` module.
    Mortal(Period, Phase),
}
```

So you have `01 2000_0000_0000_0000 0100_0000_0000_0000` (underscores added by me). The `01` implies `Mortal`; the two numbers are `Period` and `Phase`. They are hex dumps in SCALE (Little Endian) format, meaning that the first bytes are the least significant, so these two numbers are just: `32` (`Period`) and `1` (`Phase`).

Basically the transaction is valid for `Period` blocks. The `Phase` and `Period` are used along with the `current` height of the chain when the transaction is included and the chain's recent history of block hashes in order to recover a past block hash which is utilised in the transaction's signed content and must match up for the transaction's signature to check out.

Comment: My second pic show the Period is `32`, while my first pic use Lifetime: `64`, this cause signature mis-match. when I change Lifetime to `32`, the signature is matched.